# Liferay Spring MVC permission checker

Tags: spring, permissions, liferay

I need to create custom permission for roles to show/hide `div's` and `buttons` depending on the user role. On the Internet, I can not find custom permission to Liferay 7.1 with  Spring MVC 4.3.21.

Here is a site with an example: [Create Custom Permission and Show/Hide](http://liferayiseasy.blogspot.com/2015/06/create-custom-permission-and-showhide.html).

The thing is my structure project differs from the example above.

I have a spring project.

Project structure:

```
web.xml

portlet.xml

liferay-portlet.xml

liferay-display.xml
```

spring-context (folder)

```
- spring-context
    portlet-application-context.xml
      - portlet:
          Employee-portlet.xml
```

portlet.xml

```
<portlet>
        <portlet-name>Employee</portlet-name>
        <display-name>Employee</display-name>
        <portlet-class>org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet</portlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <name>contextConfigLocation</name>
            <value>/WEB-INF/spring-context/portlet/Employee-portlet.xml</value>
        </init-param>
        <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
        <supports>
            <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
        </supports>
        <portlet-info>
            <title>Employee</title>
            <short-title>Employee</short-title>
            <keywords>Employee</keywords>
        </portlet-info>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>administrator</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>guest</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>power-user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
    </portlet>
```

Employee-portlet.xml

```
<bean id="portletModeHandlerMapping"
          class="org.springframework.web.portlet.handler.PortletModeHandlerMapping">
        <property name="portletModeMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="view">
                    <ref bean="employeeV## Heading ##iewController" />
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Forgive my curiosity, nut I wonder if it is mandatory for you to use spring in Liferay 7.1. Are you deploying a WAB ? If it is not the case why don't you create an OSGi component as a portlet ?
Otherwise, you can find many threads about defining/calling permission chercker in Liferay 7.1 here : https://dev.liferay.com/fr/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-1/checking-permissions

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the problem so far. Are the ResourceActions (Permission) not created? Do you have a resource-action-mapping xml file to define your custom permissions? Is there yet a resource.actions.configs Portlet property to point on this xml file? Basically, defining custom permission in DXP Spring Portlet is possible. Or do you have problem on checking a permission with the permission Checker?